# PHP: Stripe API does not display any error when entering a bad card number

Tags: php, stripe-payments

It seems I am missing something when trying to handle some errors with Stripe in test mode with PHP.

Payment are successful when I enter a test card number like 4242424242424242 (for VISA) but I have no error and nothing is recorded when I enter a bad card number.

It is like if the button "Pay" was not working although it displays an error message if I use a real correct card number in test mode.

Does someone know what am I doing wrong here ? Thanks.

Here is the PHP code :

```
// Check whether stripe token is not empty 
if(!empty($_POST['stripeToken'])){ 
     
    // Retrieve stripe token, card and user info from the submitted form data 
    $token  = $_POST['stripeToken']; 
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $card_number = $_POST['card_number']; 
    $card_exp_month = $_POST['card_exp_month']; 
    $card_exp_year = $_POST['card_exp_year']; 
    $card_cvc = $_POST['card_cvc']; 
    $itemPrice = $_POST['itemPrice']; 
    $itemNumber = $_POST['itemNumber'];
    $Ticket_number = $_POST['Ticket_number'];

    // Include Stripe PHP library 
    require_once 'stripe-php/init.php'; 
     
    // Set API key 
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_API_KEY); 
     
    // Add customer to stripe 
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array( 
        'email' => $email, 
        'source'  => $token 
    )); 
      
    // Unique order ID 
    $orderID = strtoupper(str_replace('.','',uniqid('', true))); 
     
    // Convert price to cents 
    $itemPrice = ($itemPrice*100); 
     
    // Charge a credit or a debit card 
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array( 
        'customer' => $customer->id, 
        'amount'   => $itemPrice, 
        'currency' => $currency, 
        'description' => $itemName, 
        'metadata' => array( 
            'order_id' => $orderID 
        ) 
    )); 
     
    // Retrieve charge details 
    $chargeJson = $charge->jsonSerialize(); 
 
    // Check whether the charge is successful 
    if($chargeJson['amount_refunded'] == 0 && empty($chargeJson['failure_code']) && $chargeJson['paid'] == 1 && $chargeJson['captured'] == 1){ 
        // Order details  
        $transactionID = $chargeJson['balance_transaction']; 
        $paidAmount = $chargeJson['amount']; 
        $paidCurrency = $chargeJson['currency']; 
        $payment_status = $chargeJson['status']; 
         
        // Include database connection file  
        include_once 'dbConnect.php';
        $itemPrice = ($itemPrice/100);
        $paidAmount = ($paidAmount/100);
         
        // Insert tansaction data into the database 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders(name,email,card_number,card_exp_month,card_exp_year,item_name,item_number,item_price,item_price_currency,paid_amount,paid_amount_currency,txn_id,payment_status,created,modified) VALUES('".$name."','".$email."','".$card_number."','".$card_exp_month."','".$card_exp_year."','".$itemName."','".$itemNumber."','".$itemPrice."','".$currency."','".$paidAmount."','".$paidCurrency."','".$transactionID."','".$payment_status."',NOW(),NOW())"; 
        $insert = $db->query($sql); 
        $payment_id = $db->insert_id; 
         
        // If the order is successful 
        if($payment_status == 'succeeded'){ 
            $ordStatus = 'success'; 
            $statusMsg = ''; 
        }else{ 
            $statusMsg = "Your Payment has Failed!"; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        print '<pre>';print_r($chargeJson); 
        $statusMsg = "Transaction has been failed!";
        
    } 
}else{ 
    $statusMsg = "Error on form submission.";
    
} 
?>
```

Comment: You want to wrap it with a `try`-`catch` statement

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers but in fact it was a dummy mistake : I did not declare an id to display my error. I had to add the following code in my form :

```
<p id="payment-status" role="alert"></p>
```